# Paypal card validation before payment process start

Tags: joomla, paypal

Is there any way for validating paypal cardnumber before starting payment process?
Now,my paypal payment will work only if cardnumber is 16 digit.
suppose if i enter 14 digit number,it show error like this :

cardnumber invalid

This is not any response from paypal.is there anyway for validating card number before payment process start?

Comment: There are lots of algorithms & code around for validating card numbers if you want to do so yourself. Look around. But be careful: even the first validation you propose (check # of digits) is based on a misconception (not all valid card #s on the major card networks must be exactly 16 digits). So if you do add your own validation "in front" of your card processor (which will of course check validity when you ask for the authorization) make sure you are not overfiltering.

Comment: @ geewiz   , i have seen one algorithm for credit card validation.luhn algorithm?i have tested it with some credit card numberalso.working fine only.but still i am confused whether it will block valid card number also?

Comment: Yes, account #s aka PANs should all follow ISO/IEC 7812, which as wikipedia explains here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number always includes a Luhn checksum digit.